# Google App Script new editor - it shows errors in my code, but how to see what is wrong?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the Google App Script new editor. I declared a variable mindt, gave it an empty string as its initial value, and assigned with a value from a query (showing below). The new editor indicated that I have an error with the new assignment statement for mindt. How can I find out why the new editor thinks I have an error? Thanks!

```
 var maxdt = "";
 ... ...
 var cols = rows[0].f;
 mindt = cols[0].v;
```

Comment: Can you share the full code you are using? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: The editor did not give any error message. All the new editor did was underlining the variable mindt indicating that there is an error. In Visual Studio, it suggests fixes and gives explanations. I wish the same here.

Comment: Can you share all of your code, please? Does your code run?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using console.log to print out the error

```
console.log(mindt)
```

or

```
Logger.log(mindt)
```

Comment: mxLiew, thank you for the suggestion. These log the value. I still cannot tell what why the new editor thinks I have an error.